# CS:GO "LAN" Servers

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I want to host a server on "de_dust2" from my PC, with another user able to join. I'd like us two to be the only joined, whilst the other players are BOTS.

Another note is the player I want to join is not on the same network, so it isn't a LAN, so do I need a virtual LAN and provide the public IP for direct connect?

I have read up on this and have the following solutions:

1. Join a public server that's empty;
2. Create a lobby and start Offline with BOT.

I have not been able to perform the following. Is anyone able to provide an example on how to do this?

I'd preferably like a .cfg file to connect to a server with BOTS and also acquire the server IP for direct connect.

Comment: SteamCMD is your friend here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason you could not do this. Just a bit of fiddling with some Console commands.

The best route I'd say but may require some knowledge of steam console commands is to use a Dedicated server.

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Dedicated_Servers

You can host a server and provided you open the approproiate ports on the firewall your friend can join. You need only set a password to the server and boom. Private server for you both.

Join the server and then add some bots!

To add bots you can either do this in-game via "developers console" or use the console on the Dedicated Server program.

Can look messy but it is actually rather simple to do bots.

```
"bot_quota_mode"     "fill"
"bot_defer_to_human_items"   "1"
"bot_defer_to_human_goals"   "0"
"bot_difficulty"     "1"
"bot_dont_shoot"     "0"
"bot_chatter"        "normal"
"bot_autodifficulty_threshold_low" "-2.0"  // Value between -20.0 and 20.0 (Amount below avg human contribution score, below which a bot should raise its difficulty)
"bot_autodifficulty_threshold_high"  "0.0" // Value between -20.0 and 20.0 (Amount above avg human contribution score, above which a bot should lower its difficulty)
```

Again all the above is listed on the site i linked above. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the lobby way:

1. Invite player to lobby.
2. Set permissions to Private Match by clicking the permissions button once.
3. Choose gamemode.
4. Go, and you should load into a server. Bots should already be there.